# How to uninstall nosetests?

Tags: python, ubuntu, nose

On `Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS`, how can I uninstall `nosetests`? Neither `apt remove xxx` not `pip uninstall xxx` works for `xxx={nose, nosetests}`.

I think I have a corrupt `nosetest` installation because:

```
>nosetests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 23, in <module>
    import gettext
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 91
    raise ValueError, \
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 12, in <module>
    import subprocess, tempfile, os.path, re, pwd, grp, os, time
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 725
    raise exc_type, exc_value, exc_trace
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 23, in <module>
    import gettext
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 91
    raise ValueError, \
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `which nosetests`? `which pip`? `which pip3`? this looks like a python2/python3 conflict

Comment: `which nosetests`: nothing (?). -> it was not installed in the first place. Ah and I get the same error for ANYTHING not installed. So the problem is somwewhere else...

Comment: hmm, anything funny in `echo $PYTHONPATH`? Also you can do `pip freeze`and `pip3 freeze` and check what's installed in each

Comment: Yes I will check. Thanks for the input